# Как сленговое "шестерка" переводится на английский?

Tags: перевод

Как сленговое "шестерка" переводится на английский?

Comment: (Somebody's) bootlicker.

Comment: [шестёрка](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%F8%E5%F1%F2%B8%F0%EA%E0), [мальчик на побегушках](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%EC%E0%EB%FC%F7%E8%EA%20%ED%E0%20%EF%EE%E1%E5%E3%F3%F8%EA%E0%F5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Grunt" вполне подойдёт, хотя наверняка найдутся другие варианты перевода.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/9300)

Comment: He asked "How to translate". I provided a possible translation. How come it's not an answer?

Comment: Sorry for confusing, this comment was generated automatically during the review. My opinion was that the answer is quite short and actually should be a comment, but choosing the corresponding option in the review leads to such confusing comment.